# Pentaho data alimention

Tags: database, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a large KJB that feeds DMT and DWH. I want to know how a job, which contains a KTR or KJB, can be set up to require completion of another job before it starts its work. I am looking for a generic test to determine whether one function needs another, even if I change tables, so that I don't have to modify the large KJB every time I change a table. I have tried an old solution, but I am still encountering this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A job (extension file *.kjb) will execute steps serially, it doesn't launch the next step until the previous step is finished, you can add hops to next steps inconditionally, or you can add hops with the condition correct and/or error (one step in a job can have hops to more than one step).

Is the transactions (extension file *.ktr) the ones that inialize all the steps at the beginning and the steps wait for the stream of data to reach the step to process that stream.

You can inject metadata to transactions to execute the same operation on different tables, so you could use a transaction to insert data into different tables and you call the same transaction numerous times in the job just changing the metadata you are injecting (table name, column names, etc)

Comment: thank you again Ana GH for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure how exactly your KJB is, but when you create multiple KTR  for each progress and using that each KTR as hop in JOB, you can make sure that the next KTR will execute only when previous process is completed.

Comment: yes !  you right , the probleme is that how i could know in general if the next job need specific ktr or job  to be finished or table to be alimented  ! thank you for your answer Rajen Raiyarela